# Python - Detecting desired corners of a image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, corner-detection

I need help in python coding an algorithm capable of detecting the corners of a image. I have a thresholded image so far and I was using cornerHarris from opencv to detect all the corners. My problem is filtrating all those points to output only the ones I desired. Maybe I can do a loop to achieve this?

In my case, I want the two lowest corners and the two highest corners points. My main interest is to obtain the pixel coordinates of this corners. You can see an example of a image I'm processing here:
[image]

In this image I draw the corners points I'm interested in.

Comment: how about sorting on the basis of y values and finding 2 lowest extreme and 2 highest extreme corresponding points.

Comment: I have managed to detect the corners, now I'm going to extract the ones I'm interested by following your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem. In real-world applications it's rare (that is, actually never occurs) that you need to solve a problem once for a single image. If you have additional images it would be nice to see how much the object of interest varies.

One method to find corners is the convex hull. This method is more generally used to find a convex shape encompassing scattered points, but it's worth knowing about and implementing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

What's handy about the convex hull is that the concept of a "corner" (a vertex on the convex hull polygon) is easy to grasp and doesn't rely on parameter settings. You don't have to consider whether a corner is sharp enough, strong enough, pointy enough, unique in its neighborhood, etc.--the convex hull will simply make sense to you.

You should be able to write a functional version of a convex hull "gift wrapping" algorithm in a reasonable period of time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

There are many ways to compute the convex hull, but don't get lost in all the different methods. Choose one that makes sense to you and implement it. The fastest known method may still be Seidel, but don't even think about running down that rabbit hole. Simple is good.

Before you compute the convex hull, you'll need to reduce your white shape to edge points; otherwise the hull algorithm will check far too many points. Reducing the number of points to be considered can be done using edge-finding on the connected component (the white "blob"), edge-finding without first segmenting foreground from background, or any of various simple kernels (e.g. Sobel).

Although the algorithm is called the "convex" hull, your shape doesn't have to be convex, especially if you're only interested in the top and bottom vertices/corners as shown in your sample image.

Corner finders can be a bit disappointing, frankly, especially since the name implies, "Hey, it'll just find corners all the time." There are some good ones out there, but you could spend a lot of time investigating all the alternatives. Even then you'll likely have to set thresholds, consider whether your application will yield the occasional weird result given the shape and scale of corners, and so on.

Although you mention wanting to find only the top and bottom points, if you wanted to find those two odd triangular outcroppings on the left side the corner-finding gets a little more complicated;  using the convex hull keeps this very simple.

Although you want to find a robust solution to corner detection, preferably using a known algorithm for which performance can be understood easily, you also want to avoid overgeneralizing. In any case, review some list of corner detectors and see what strikes your fancy. If you see a promising algorithm that looks easy-ish to implement, why not try implementing it?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection